# R euclidian ring with field of fractions K:

Tags: abstract-algebra

$a$ ≠ 0 element of $K$. I have to show that $a$ can be written as

$a$ = $r/s$, $r,s$ belong to R \ {0} and r and s are coprime.

I know that for def. every element of K can be written as $cb^-1$=$c/b$

I don't think that saying $c=r$ and $b=s$ is enough, this isn't a proof, but I don't know how could I demonstrate that

Comment: Have you already proved that gcds exist?

Comment: @BillDubuque yes

Comment: Then why not simply cancel $\gcd(r,s)$ from the fraction, just like in $\,\Bbb Q?\ \ $